Creating a project management file in google sheets. Need help adding row to the top of the complete tab
I am creating a project management file in google sheets.
I'm looking to move rows from a "Tasks" tab to a "Complete" tab once a check box complete is marked.
I currently have it working except it adds the row to the bottom of the complete tab instead of the top ideally like it to sort chronologically with the newest complete tasks are on the top.
This is the script I have so far. I tried changing the .getLastrow to .getFirstrow but did not work.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
 function onEdit(e) {
 const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 const r = e.range;
 if (src.getName() != "Tasks" || r.columnStart != 7 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
 const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,7).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7));
 src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
 }


It is usually easier to use a table with the Group by view.

Transferring Data to another sheet using Checkbox
I modified your code and used appendRow and this is the output base on the Question and Comment you've given.

Now, is there a simple way to move the completed task on the "complete" tab back to the "tasks" tab to the top in a similar way? by unchecking the complete box


Sample Output:


Code:
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() == "Tasks" && r.columnStart == 7 && r.rowStart != 1) {
    if (r.getValue()) {
      const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
      dest.appendRow(src.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0]);
      src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
      dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(), 7).insertCheckboxes();
      dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(), 7).check();
    }
  } else if (src.getName() == "Complete" && r.columnStart == 7 && r.rowStart != 1) {
    if (!r.getValue()) {
      const ret = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tasks");
      ret.appendRow(src.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0]);
      src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
      ret.getRange(ret.getLastRow(), 7).insertCheckboxes();
      ret.getRange(ret.getLastRow(), 7).uncheck();
    }
  }
}

Note: It also works with any Checkboxes within Column 7 Starts at Row 2.

References:

AppendRow



How about first creating a new empty row at the top of the destination sheet, then moving the row there?
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Tasks" || r.columnStart != 7 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
  dest.insertRows(2);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,7).moveTo(dest.getRange(2,1,1,7));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
 }


That's better!
But its adding it above my headers.
How would I have it add to the essentially row 2?

I edited the code for it to move it to row 2. The dest.insertRows(2) tells the Google God to insert a row at index 2; then the .moveTo(dest.getRange(2, 1, 1, 7)) pastes your data in a range consisting of 1 row and 7 columns, starting at row 2 and column 1.

Now, is there a simple way to move the completed task on the "complete" tab back to the "tasks" tab to the top in a similar way? by unchecking the complete box
